# Unable to Perform Search Using Spring Data Elasticsearch and Elasticsearch High-Level REST Client

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to implement a partial search functionality in my Spring Boot application using Spring Data Elasticsearch and the Elasticsearch High-Level REST Client. I have a method partialSearchUsers in my service class that constructs a SearchQuery object based on the provided parameters (name, email, address, phone, sortField, and sortOrder) and performs a search operation on the Elasticsearch index. However, the search is not working as expected, and I'm not getting the desired results.

Here's my code:

```
public List<UserDto> partialSearchUsers(String name, String email, String address, String phone, String sortField, String sortOrder) {

// Create a SearchQuery object.
SearchQuery searchQuery = new SearchQuery();

// Add criteria to the SearchQuery object.
if (name != null) {
    searchQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").contains(name));
}

if (email != null) {
    searchQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("email").contains(email));
}

if (address != null) {
    searchQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("address").contains(address));
}

if (phone != null) {
    searchQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("phone").contains(phone));
}

// Add a sort to the SearchQuery object.
if (sortField != null && sortOrder != null) {
    searchQuery.addSort(Sort.by(Sort.Order.fromString(sortOrder), sortField));
}

// Execute the search query and retrieve the results.
List<User> users = userRepo.search(searchQuery);

return userMapper.map(users);
```

}

I have included the necessary dependencies in my project:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
<artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
<version>7.17.9</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using Java 17. Can someone please help me identify what might be causing the issue? Is there something I am missing in my code or configuration? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What version of Spring Data Elasticsearch are you using? There is no `SearchQuery` in the current version and the repository method taking a query object has been removed in 4.0 as far as I remember (which was more than 3 years ago).

Comment: i am using `spring-data-dlasticsearch:5.1.5` version.

Comment: I want to perform partialSearch and fullSearch (with another method) of users based on parameters that are not null. Could you please help me decide which version to go with?

Comment: "However, the search is not working as expected, and I'm not getting the desired results." This phrase can mean pretty much anything from getting exception to relevancy being slightly off. Could you explain what you mean by that statement?

Comment: As I wrote, there is no `SearchQuery` class in Spring Data Elasticsearch 5.1, and no repository method taking a query object. So the code doing the search must be implemented somewhere outside of Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Comment: Can you share the results ? Exceptions, errors ect..